# Microsoft Graph C# Schedule Meeting

Tags: c#, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to schedule events in my O365 user calendars.
I'm using an administrator account, creating a GraphServiceClient on authentication.
There are no errors (apparently) but the event is not created. Neither on the account used nor on the Attendees.
It seems to me that the problem is in the authorization of the GraphServiceClient. I already checked in the Azure portal and the user has "Calendars.ReadWrite" permission.
Any help, please?

```
try
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "Calendars.ReadWrite.All" };

            // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
            // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
            var tenantId = "common";

            Configuracoes Dados = new Configuracoes();

            // Values from app registration
            string clientId = Dados.EMailCV.ToString();
            string clientSecret = Dados.PasswordCV.ToString();

            // using Azure.Identity;
            var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            };

            // This is the incoming token to exchange using on-behalf-of flow
            var oboToken = "JWT_TOKEN_TO_EXCHANGE";

            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .Build();

            // DelegateAuthenticationProvider is a simple auth provider implementation
            // that allows you to define an async function to retrieve a token
            // Alternatively, you can create a class that implements IAuthenticationProvider
            // for more complex scenarios
            var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
            {
                // Use Microsoft.Identity.Client to retrieve token
                var assertion = new UserAssertion(oboToken);
                var result = await cca.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, assertion).ExecuteAsync();

                request.Headers.Authorization =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            });

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var @event = new Event
            {
                Subject = "Let's go for lunch",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = "Does noon work for you?"
                },
                Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2022-11-04T12:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time"
                },
                End = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2017-04-15T14:00:00",
                    TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time"
                },
                // Location = new Location
                // {
                //     displayName = "Harry's Bar"
                // },
                Attendees = new List<Attendee>()
                {
                    new Attendee
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "p560@esenviseu.net",
                            Name = "Nuno Barros"
                        },
                        Type = AttendeeType.Required
                    }
                },
                AllowNewTimeProposals = true,
                IsOnlineMeeting = true,
                OnlineMeetingProvider = OnlineMeetingProviderType.TeamsForBusiness
            };

            graphClient.Me.Events
                .Request()
                .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"GMT Standard Time\"")
                .AddAsync(@event);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblTexto.Text = "Erros!<br>" + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            lblTexto.Text = "Sem erros!";
        }
```

Comment: If you were getting authentication errors, than they should show up in Event Viewer.  Check response for status code.  It should be 200 OK.  A error response will not give an exception.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors?force_isolation=true

Comment: As I said, I get no errors and any kind of response... Where to check the Event Viewer? 
I'm using a O365 subscription (educational license).
I've checked the Azure Portal but I don't see any interaction from the user I'm using...

Comment: I assume you are sending the request.  A few things can be happening 1) You are using TLS (HTTPS not HTTP) and TLS is failing.  TLS is sent before the request is sent and request will not be sent if TLS fails.  No response will be received. 2) You server isn't running and connection fails.  You will not get response 3) Your connection completes and request is sent.  So you will always get a response.  Good response will have status 200 OK.  Bad response will have status not equal 200 OK.  Normally you would get an exception with 1 or 2 and no exception with 3.  I think the connection is good.

Comment: strange pattern to call only .AddAsync(@event) because it returns task and you do not wait for completion. Try to use `var addedEvent = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request().Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"GMT Standard Time\"").AddAsync(@event);` or `var addedEvent = graphClient.Me.Events.Request().Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"GMT Standard Time\"").AddAsync(@event).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`